# More elegant way to express ((x == a && y == b) || (x == b && y == a))?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to evaluate `((x == a && y == b) || (x == b && y == a))` in **Swift**, but it seems a bit verbose. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you need to to check this in tests target?

Comment: Sometimes yes. But these kind of expressions happens everywhere.

Comment: Please note that the more elegant ways shown in the answers are more "elegant" but they seem also to need more resources (runtime and/or memory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the elements are **Hashable**, you can use `Set`:

```
Set([a,b]) == Set([x,y])
```

If they not, you can use `tuple`s to get rid of many extra symbols:

```
(a,b) == (x,y) || (a,b) == (y,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that can be used for checking more than 2 elements and doesn't require the elements to be `Hashable`, only `Equatable` (but with duplicate elements, it doesn't check whether they appear the same number of times in both arrays or not, just that they appear at least once, just like the `Set`-based solution):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func containsSameElements(as otherArray: Self) -> Bool {
        return otherArray.allSatisfy { contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[1,2,3].containsSameElements(as: [1,2,3]) // true
[1,2,3].containsSameElements(as: [1,2,3,4]) // false
[1,2,3].containsSameElements(as: [4,2,3]) // false
[1,2,3].containsSameElements(as: [3,2,1]) // true
```

Comment: This may behave unexpectedly if there are duplicate values, though.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery that's right, updated my answer with that fact (the `Set` based solution also disregards duplicates though, so this behaves the same way as the `Set` based solution actually)

Answer (score 0):

Extensions?

```
struct EqualityChecker<T: Equatable> {

    private let x: T
    private let y: T

    init(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

    static func ==(l: EqualityChecker<T>, r: EqualityChecker<T>) -> Bool {
        return (l.x == r.x && l.y == r.y) || (l.x == l.y && l.y == r.x)
    }
}

extension Numeric {

    func either(_ numbers: Self...) -> Bool {
        for number in numbers {
            if number == self { return true }
        }
        return false
    }

    func and(_ x: Self) -> EqualityChecker<Self> {
        return EqualityChecker(self, x)
    }
}

if x.either(a, b) && y.either(a, b) {
    // This is equal to ((x == a || x == b) && (y == a || y == b))
}

// Yours:
if x.and(y) == a.and(b) {
    // This is equal to ((x == a && y == b) || (x == b && y == a))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant yes.  Faster, not so much (note I think the Array is still better than a Set here since its only 2 elements, but as n gets larger then obviously a Set will be faster):

```
[a,b].contains(x) && [a,b].contains(y)
```

Comment: This is not technically the same Boolean test. This would also pass for x == a && y== a which is not a pass condition.